# Hide a shipping method frontend and still show in backend

Tags: shipping, ce-1.9.0.1, shipping-methods, stores

I want hide a shipping method in frontend and that only show in backend. Is possible enable pickup store only in backend? I make with payment methods very easy

> protected $_canUseInternal = true;
>   protected $_canUseCheckout = false;

but with shipping is impossible for me. Could your help me please? Thanks in advance

Comment: Check this http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-hide-shipping-method-on-magento-frontend-but-leave-it-on-in-admin-area/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following blog could help you:

- http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/how-to-filter-shipping-method-in-onepage-checkout/

Comment: Hi @Rahul Kumar Das i used custom shipping method. it will work

Answer (score 5):

Just incase the site given in another answer goes down for some reason.

You may want to filter shipping method in onepage checkout for one of the following cases:

- Filter shipping method based on Customer Group
- Filter Shipping method based on Country, State, Zipcode etc
- Filter Shipping method based on products
- etc.

Unlike event: ‘**payment_method_is_active**’ for payment method filtration, we don’t have a similar event: ‘**shipping_method_is_active**’ available for shipping method.

Whatever may be the reason we still can filter by overriding: `Mage_Shipping_Model_Shipping::collectCarrierRates()`

Solution
Suppose a skeleton module(MagePsycho_Shipmentfilter) has already been created. And for example purpose we will be hiding flat rate shipping for non-logged in customer.

1. Rewrite the shipping model class: ‘Mage_Shipping_Model_Shipping’
   File: app/code/local/MagePsycho/Shipmentfilter/etc/config.xml

> ```
> ...
> <global>
>     ...
>     <models>
>         <shipping>
>             <rewrite>
>                 <shipping>MagePsycho_Shipmentfilter_Model_Shipping</shipping>
>             </rewrite>
>         </shipping>
>     </models>
>     ...
> </global>
> ```

2. Override the method: collectCarrierRates()

File: app/code/local/MagePsycho/Shipmentfilter/Model/Shipping.php

```
class MagePsycho_Shipmentfilter_Model_Shipping extends 
Mage_Shipping_Model_Shipping {
    public function collectCarrierRates($carrierCode, $request) {
        if (!$this - > _checkCarrierAvailability($carrierCode, $request)) {
            return $this;
        }
        return
        parent::collectCarrierRates($carrierCode, $request);
    }
    protected function _checkCarrierAvailability($carrierCode, $request = null) {
        $isLoggedIn = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session') - > isLoggedIn();
        if (!$isLoggedIn) {
            if ($carrierCode == 'flatrate') {
                # Hide Flat Rate
                for non logged in customers
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

3. That’s all.